# Issue with Error handling using .catch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm making calls to Reddits API inside of React using snoowrapper, a wrapper for JS which you can find [here](https://not-an-aardvark.github.io/snoowrap/index.html). But I came into an issue where every time I tried to call the function that uses snoowrapper, it returns `Unhandled Rejection (Error): 404` and breaks the webpage instead of handling the error and logging.

Here's my what I have so far.

### Relevant Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Snoowrap from "snoowrap";

function Homepage(props) {
  const [LinkInput, setLinkInput] = useState("");

  
  const updateInputValue = (evt) => {
    setLinkInput(evt.target.value);
  };

const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');

const handleLinkVerify = () => {
  const r = new snoowrap({
    userAgent: 'windows:testbot:v1.0.0 (by /u/xxxx)',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    username: "xxxxxx",
    password: "xxxxx",
  });
  r.getSubmission("ozbtjrr")
     .then(submission => console.log(submission.author.name))
     .catch(console.log('error'));
}

  return (
        <>
          <Button
            variant="outline-light"
            id="analyze-button"
            size="lg"
            onClick={() => handleLinkVerify()}
          >
            Analyze
          </Button>
    </>
  );
}
export default Homepage;
```

### Output

`Unhandled Rejection (Error): 404` and visible frustration

### What I tried

I've since tried to use `.then` and `.catch` but it didn't work either. It was recommended to do

```
r.getSubmission("ozbtjrr")
  .then(submission => console.log(submission.author.name))
  .catch(console.log('error');
```

by someone else, but that only results in `getSubmission is not a function` since it needs to precede with `.author` or some parameter right after.

Honestly thats the only thing I've tried. It's really taking me the entire day to figure this out, so if you have any tips I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please show runnable code as an [mcve]. Based on your naming, it's highly unlikely that `name` is a promise, but that's just a guess. If you're using `.then`, use `.catch` instead of `try`-`catch`. The second blottom block makes more sense, but if `getSubmission` isn't a function, please explain/show what `r` is.

Comment: `.catch(console.log('error');` will throw a syntax error. There is a parenthesis missing at the end. Also `console.log('error')` will log "error" immediately, regardless of the actual outcome. You are essentially passing `undefined` (the result of calling console.log) as the callback function. Try `.catch(error => console.log(error));`.

Comment: more to the above: in fact if you fix the syntax `.catch(console.log('error'));` not only will `error`  be logged to the console immediately regardless of any error or not, you are not actually adding a rejection handler, which is why you get the unhandled rejection warning

Comment: I expanded on the relevant code to show the entire file that I'm working with. This is a working example in React (which also behaves the same way in JS) of what I'm experiencing. I'm not sure how to move forward since I don't know if the call is even a Promise; I think its a wrapper for one.